# How to convert WAV files of some frequency to 44100 Hertz?

Tags: wav, audio-conversion

I'm using Source Filmmaker, and need to convert an audio file I have to 44100 Hertz, otherwise SFM will not accept it.

I believe the frequency of the file is less than 44100 Hertz, and therefore will increase in size as a result of conversion (it's a sound file from CNC RA2, if that's relevant).  I would like to convert the file directly, so as to reduce quality loss, and converting to an MP3 and back is a last resort.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 44100 output.wav
```

There's really no need to convert to MP3 as an intermediate format.

Answer (score 3):

Using SoX:

```
sox -S input.wav output.wav rate -L -s 44100
```

If you are making Red-Book Audio CDs use this command:

```
sox -S input.wav output.wav channels 2 rate -L -s 44100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at Audacity (http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

It's a simple audio editing software which will allow you to change this rate.

- Import your file in audacity (File -> Open)
- At the head of the track, clicking the arrow (on top of `mute` button) will open a menu, in which you can set the rate to whatever you need.
- Then export it (File -> Export), and select your format. Select `Other uncompressed files` if you need 24 or 32bits WAV, the `Options` button will allow you to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org): open your file, change the project rate, and export as WAV.

[image]

Comment: Franck, this seems pretty similar to Levans' answer.

Comment: @fixer1234  Levans' answer points to a different menu option, which in Audacity 2.2.2 will slow down the audio file.

Comment: Yeah. I tried all these solutions and ended up needing to use SoX